# How to either return JSON or RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction, jsonresult

I have an Action Method that I'd either like to return JSON from on one condition or redirect on another condition. I thought that I could do this by returning ActionResult from my method but doing this causes the error "not all code paths return a value"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or how to achieve the desired result?

Here's the code below:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        var myErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        try
            {


                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (userRepository.ValidUser(user))
                    {
                        RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
                        //return Json("Valid");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json("Invalid");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> keyValuePair in ViewData.ModelState)
                    {
                        if (keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                        {
                            List<string> errors = new List<string>();

                            myErrors.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                        }

                    }
                    return Json(myErrors);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json("Invalid");
            }

        }
```

**Edit:** to clarify, I've already tried to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");` as suggested in the answers but it doesn't do anything. The breakpoint in the action I'm redirecting to doesn't get hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything. I put a breakpoint into the Action I'm redirecting to but that doesn't get hit. I've updated the question with this. Thanks

Comment: Is this in an action method that only accepts a Post and you are trying to redirect to an action that only accepts a Get? I've been tripped up by that before. Kindness, Dan

Answer (score 0):

you shold return RedirectResult. Change this string

```
if (userRepository.ValidUser(user))
                    {
                        RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
                        //return Json("Valid");
                    }
```

to

```
if (userRepository.ValidUser(user))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
                        //return Json("Valid");
                    }
```

and all will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a return statement:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
```

The [`Controller.RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594.aspx) method returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` and
[`Controller.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936.aspx) method returns a `JsonResult`. Both extend `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your redirect is not getting where you want is that it is directing to an action that accepts only Gets and you are redirecting a Post.